# Global Pointer "already defined in" error

Tags: c++

I'm writing a little DirectX model viewer.

I just finished writing my scene manger.

I will only ever have 1 scene manger object so my idea was to create a global pointer of type "scnManger" and then set it when i create my scene manger object.

This would let me get to it from any where in my application.

I'm getting a compile error though:

```
1>shaderViewer.obj : error LNK2005: "class scnManger * sceneManger" (?sceneManger@@3PAVscnManger@@A) already defined in sceneManager.obj
1>C:\Users\Greg\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ShaderViewer\Debug\ShaderViewer.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

right now I have 3 files

sceneManger.h:

```
// Our global scene manger variable

scnManger* sceneManger;
```

shadherViewer.cpp (winMain & includes sceneManger.h):

```
scnManger shaderViewerScnManger; 
sceneManger = &shaderViewerScnManger;
```

sceneManger.cpp (includes sceneManger.h):

I use the methods of my scene manger object in here for various things.

First I would like to understand why I am getting the error, and am also open to any suggestions about a better way to handle this.  I wasn't sure if using a global variable like this was a good idea or not.

Comment: Are you setting `sceneManager` in global scope in `shaderViewer.cpp`?

Comment: no I am not, I don't I only declare it once in the .h file which I include in shaderViewer.cpp, then I just set it like you see above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not define global variables in .h files. You should declare them in .h, like this:

```
extern scnManger* sceneManger;
```

and then define them in *one* cpp file, like this:

```
scnManger* sceneManger;
```

Otherwise, every cpp file that includes your .h file will declare the `sceneManger` variable, resulting in a name collision.

Comment: That makes sense, one thing I did was set it to static when I defined it, then my program compile fine...

I'm not really sure what static does though, I just saw it in another example and tried it.  Could someone explain why that worked?

Comment: @user1372122 making it `static` in .h makes each variable visible only in its own compilation unit (i.e. a cpp file from which you included the .h). This avoids name collisions by declaring separate independent variables, but it defeats the purpose of making the variable global, because now you have separate independent pointers instead of a single global pointer.